# GRUB: no such device

Tags: linux, grub, linux-mint, bootloader

I had to reinstall Mint recently and after reinstalling, I get an error in GRUB:

```
error: no such device: *hex-hex-hex*
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have tried a bunch of things, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows), with no luck. I also found a guide for using grub rescue, but the second command it wanted me to execute failed with something like `could not read filesystem`. I forget the exact error and I can't find that guide again.

Basically, I need to know how to figure out what my computer is looking for when it boots, and why GRUB is trying to find a device that isn't there.

EDIT:

[With external plugged in](http://pastebin.com/MVL3KdAL)
[Without external plugged in](http://pastebin.com/AMGY2kZm)

The device it says its looking for is `94cf97c7-aa0f-48d7-8c9f-42fd51dc1a1a`

Comment: What happens if you go to the BIOS boot selection (I forget the key in Vista, typically F12 or Esc), and select a different drive to boot from?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'll give it a shot. I think i tried that once before and couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You have to be fast.  When you reboot or turn on the computer, there is a brief display of the option and it will say to press a particular key.  You only have a couple of seconds to press it before it starts to boot with the current settings.

Comment: I meant I couldn't figure out how to check the drive order. But turns out i figured it out this time and it seems to have solved the problem. It looks like i accidentally installed grub on my windows drive, so when i repartitioned to reinstall, that version of grub didn't get updated. By reordering the drives, it now loads the version installed on the Linux drive and I'm able to load both OSes.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  There are two boot option keys.  One is for a boot menu and one is to enter setup.  If you go to setup, one of the options there lets you "permanently" (until you go back and change it), define the order in which devices will be used to boot.  It is generally a good idea to put a CD/DVD and/or external drive ahead of your hard disk.  This gives you an easy way to boot if there is a problem (these are bypassed if nothing is there).  The boot menu lets you manually select a boot device for just that startup.